# is it possible to use sdkman download specify version of jdk

Tags: java

Now I could using sdkman to install java like this:

```
sdk list java
sdk install java 8.0.265.hs-adpt
```

but sometimes I just want to download specify version of java, I just want to use jdk to build docker image. Is it possible to download specify version java jdk use sdkmam? I search the docs but no one talk about it.